# How IP to connect is picked up when the Route 53 record of the domain is mapped with multiple IP addresses

Tags: dns, cloudflare, aws-route53

We have a domain registered at Cloud Flare with proxy status of the records as DNS only. There it is mapped with records of a hosted zone in AWS Route 53. The Route 53 record is of A type and it is mapped with 2 IP addresses and the routing policy is simple routing. From the documentations got to know that in this scenario, all the IPs will be returned to the DNS resolver and DNS resolver will return them to the Browser/Client and then Client will pick up an IP and connect with that Server.

On what basis, does the client picks up the IP. Is the IP chosen by Browser itself or DNS resolver provides it. Can we check what are the IPs returned to the browser.

Any assistance on this will be a great favour.

Comment: This question appears to me to be about browsers handling multiple IP DNS responses, and not actually specific to Cloudflare or AWS/Route53 at all. As such, I think it is a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3866831/how-do-browsers-handle-a-multiple-ip-response-for-a-single-hostname-from-dns

Comment: Thank you very much Mark for the response. One observation: when I accessed application from a browser, all the calls have been sent to one server. Then I made the application down in that server and switched the tab in browser. The request went to second server. Does this indicate that 2 IPs were returned to the browser. Can we check what are the IPs returned by the DNS resolver.